Use assets from node_modules in a library
I have a NX Monorepo, and in an angular library (Lib_A), I would like to access assets from the node_modules. Now normally one could add the assets to the project.json of the app itself. However, in this way, the Lib_A has an indirect dependency to the app since it should know the path to the assets in the dist folder. This is not a clean approach, isn't it? Is there any other solution so that the Lib_A could manage the assets from the node_modules itself and determine where those assets should be placed in the dist folder?
Here is my project.json
{
  "name": "lib_a",
  ...,
  "targets": {
    "test": {
      ...
    },
    "lint": {
      ...
    }
  }

}


As far as I know all monorepos inside the project share the same package.json, hence the same dependencies.
This has the advantage of not maintaining multiple dependencies and lesser problems when upgrading is my understanding.
So there is no dependency with the main app, since all share the same package.json.
You can proceed with pointing to the script inside node_modules.

Yes you're right the node_modules are shared. But when you serve the assets, only the main app or any library with "build" target could specify which assets to serve.

@MotassemJalal so what is the problem with my answer? I can't understand why we cannot serve the asset from the node_modules. you will never use the library separately on another repository, so the code is always shared and you can add to assets however you want
